# C++ OpenGL minimal VAO example

Tags: c++, opengl

Alright, so first, the reason I'm posting this is because I've seen so many tutorials that conflict with each other, and I would like to get this all straightened out. (Ignore the lack of shaders/mvp matrices/etc.)

Here is my simple example code:
[You can view it on pastebin here to make it easier to read.](https://pastebin.com/q2jWdVtq)

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <glm.hpp>

#include "Logger.h"

#include "GL.h"

namespace engine {

    using Index = unsigned int;

    struct Vertex {
        glm::vec3  position;
        glm::vec2  texcoord;
    };

    struct Mesh {
        std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
        std::vector<Index> indices;
    };

    struct MeshRenderer {
        GLsizei count;
        GLuint vao;

        ~MeshRenderer() {
            // Is this the only call needed to clean up a vao?
            glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        }
    };

    class Engine {
        Logger logger;
        MeshRenderer mr;

    public:
        Engine() :
            logger{"Engine"} {

            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);

            glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

            Mesh mesh;

            mesh.vertices.push_back({{ 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f}, {0.5f,  0.5f}});
            mesh.indices.push_back(0);

            mesh.vertices.push_back({{-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f}, {-0.5f,  0.5f}});
            mesh.indices.push_back(1);

            mesh.vertices.push_back({{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f}, {-0.5f, -0.5f}});
            mesh.indices.push_back(2);

            mr.count = mesh.indices.size();

            // Only needed temp while binding to vao.
            GLuint vbo, ibo;

            glGenVertexArrays(1, &mr.vao); // Vertex  Array  Object
            glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); // Vertex  Buffer Object (temp)
            glGenBuffers(1, &ibo); // Element Buffer Object (temp)

            glBindVertexArray(mr.vao);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), mesh.vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.indices.size() * sizeof(Index), mesh.indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(offsetof(Vertex, position)));

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(offsetof(Vertex, texcoord)));

            glBindVertexArray(0);

            // Is there any reason not to clean these up now that they have been bound to the vao?
            glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
            glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);
        }

        void onLoop(double time) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glBindVertexArray(mr.vao);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mr.count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
        }
    };
}
```

Basically, I want to know:

1. Is the VAO setup/initialization shown done correctly, or am I missing any steps or have I done anything sub optimally?
2. The way I delete the VAO (`glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);`) is that the only call I need to do to fully delete it?
3. Is it safe/good practice to delete the VBO and IBO where I do (or should I save these in until the VAO is deleted)?
4. (*Bonus points*) What would be the best way to go about updating an existing mesh? For instance if I'm rendering a grid of tiles, but I want to update the texture UVs on specific vertices, what would be the best approach for something like this? (In the past I'd rebuild the mesh manually, and make a new VAO and pass it in again. Is there a way to just add/update/delete specific vertices and/or vertex attributes?)